# mousewheel event doesn't fire over body in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mousewheel

I've noticed the **mousewheel** event doesn't fire when using the mouse wheel over the body instead of over any other element when **using the latest version of Chrome**. (38.0.2125.104 m).

This happen when using absolute positioned elements.

You can reproduce it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9pz1bec/2/) by scrolling in the white area instead of in the red ones.

Any idea why is this happening? Any solution for it?

Used code for the fiddle:

```
addMouseWheelHandler();

function addMouseWheelHandler() {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false); //IE9, Chrome, Safari, Oper
        document.addEventListener("wheel", MouseWheelHandler, false); //Firefox
    } else {
        document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler); //IE 6/7/8
    }
}



function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
    e = window.event || e;

    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.deltaY || -e.detail)));
    console.log("mouse wheel!" + delta);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is still a problem (at least on Mac Catalina). None of the suggestions work. Any solution to intercepting the mouse wheel event in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug.  The event listener is attached to the document, so it should apply to the entire document, regardless of the height of the body element.

As a work-around, you could add this code:

```
document.body.style.height= document.body.scrollHeight+'px';
```

Comment: Warning: watching document.body.scrollHeight for changes is not trivial. I had better success with adding a wrapper element inside the body and watching mousewheel on that element.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your body has no height, so you are scrolling outside of document. A parent element will not expand to the size of it's children if the children are positioned absolute. Try adding something like this:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 2000px;
}
```

or change your content from `position: absolute;`